# Why are default arguments not allowed in a Scala section with repeated parameters?

Tags: scala

According to Scala specs [Section 4.6.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters):

> It is not allowed to define any default arguments in a parameter section with a repeated parameter.

In fact, if I define the following case class:

```
case class Example(value: Option[String] = None, otherValues: String*)
```

the result I get is the expected according to the specification:

```
error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments
   case class Example(value: Option[String] = None, otherValues: String*)
```

But the question is why is this not allowed? The first argument of the class is totally independent from the repeated argument, so why is this restriction is place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you could do this:

```
case class Example(value: String = "default", otherValues: String*)
```

And now if you call `Example("Hello", "world")`, does the first `"Hello"` belongs to `value` or to `otherValues`?

You could argue that the types in your examples are different, but the rules become too complicated to follow. For example repeated parameters often used with `Any` type. This example `case class Example(value: Option[String] = None, otherValues: Any*)` has different types, but still struggles with the same problem

Comment: Right, makes total sense. After reading the answer it seems so obvious that I feel a bit dumb for not figuring it out myself :)

Comment: This ambiguity is only an ambiguity if you want it to be. Your example works perfectly fine in Ruby, for example, and Ruby doesn't even have the advantage of types guiding it. Ruby even allows mandatory positional parameters both at the beginning and the end of the (positional) parameter list. Basically, mandatory positional parameters at the beginning get bound first left-to-right, then mandatory positional parameters at the end right-to-left, then optional positional parameters left-to-right, then the rest positional parameter.

Comment: All this is followed by mandatory keyword parameters, optional keyword parameters, and lastly rest keyword parameters. So, the reason is not necessarily "it can't be made unambiguous", but rather "making it unambiguous doesn't fit well with the simplicity of the rest of the language". So, `"Hello"` gets bound to `value` and `Seq("world")` gets bound to `otherValues`, if we follow the Ruby rules, and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's what I meant as well. It's not about there is no way to write a compiler that handles that. It's about the rules that are becoming to hard to work with if it is done. And there is lots of places like that in each language. For example overloading by return type belongs to the same category. You could allow this and figure out the exact method by the required type when the call is performed, but it is complicated both for compiler and for the developer to do that, so almost no language decide to allow this